# Get tomorrows data from DB using jddayofweek

Tags: php

I am very new to this, but i was wondering if it is possible to get tomorrows data from a database using **jddayofweek** , I am using this function at the present moment and it is working perfectly to get the data todays data from the db.

**DB**

```
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
 | id        | takeaway_id | Day_of_week | Open_time  |
 +-----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
 |         1 |1            | 0           | 14:00      |
 |         2 |1            | 1           | 14:00      |
 |         3 |1            | 2           | 14:00      |
 |         4 |1            | 3           | 15:00      |
 |         5 |1            | 4           | 15:00      |
 +-----------+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I have tried the following, but it didn't work!

```
$daynum = jddayofweek(unixtojd());
$daynum->modify('+1 day');
```

So i was wondering if it is impossible using jjdayofweek.